# Set value in a column from the same column in another row in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-update

I have a select like this:

```
SELECT Number 
FROM customers
GROUP BY Number
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN customerID IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN customerID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Each group contains at least one row with `customerID = null` and at least one with `customerID` is not null.

If in group more than one rows with customerID is not null that ID`s is identical

I need an update which set customerID to rows with customerID = null from rows with customerID is not null.

How to do it?
I probably did not quite correctly describe, my select returns the following lines:

| Number | Customer id |
| --- | --- |
| 6720-7337-7464-2154 | 1167 |
| 6720-7337-7464-2154 | 1167 |
| 6720-7337-7464-2154 | NULL |
| 9543-2478-3326-1189 | 1235 |
| 9543-2478-3326-1189 | NULL |
| 9543-2478-3326-1189 | NULL |

And i need an update which make something like:

| Number | Customer id |
| --- | --- |
| 6720-7337-7464-2154 | 1167 |
| 6720-7337-7464-2154 | 1167 |
| 6720-7337-7464-2154 | 1167 |
| 9543-2478-3326-1189 | 1235 |
| 9543-2478-3326-1189 | 1235 |
| 9543-2478-3326-1189 | 1235 |

Comment: When a number has the same customerID `update c
set customerID=mincustomerID
from (select *, min(customerID) over(partition by Number) as mincustomerID,
  max(customerID) over(partition by Number) as maxcustomerID
  from customers
) as c
where c.customerID is null
and mincustomerID=maxcustomerID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use window function and Cte

then update all customers with value is null

```
;with  _list as (
       
select 
        number
        ,customerID
        ,max(customerID)
over(partition by number  ) as maxcustomerID
                 

from customers 
)

update  _list
set customerID=maxcustomerID
where customerID is null
```

You can create insert base data with the following statements:

```
drop table customers
create table customers(number varchar(100),customerID int)


insert into customers(number,customerID)values('6720-7337-7464-2154',   1167)
insert into customers(number,customerID)values('6720-7337-7464-2154',   1167)
insert into customers(number,customerID)values('6720-7337-7464-2154',   NULL)
insert into customers(number,customerID)values('9543-2478-3326-1189',   1235)
insert into customers(number,customerID)values('9543-2478-3326-1189',   NULL)
insert into customers(number,customerID)values('9543-2478-3326-1189',   NULL)
```

Comment: I edited my code based on your example data and your  expected

Comment: Thank you, it work, but update CustomerID only in one number, meybe because my number format are: '6720-7337-7464-2154' (text)? 
It's possible to fix it?

Comment: I have change example table

Comment: thank you . I edited my code base on your new change